# HTML Description List <dl> to CSV Bash tools

Tags: html, csv, web-scraping

I'm still new to page scraping and I'm trying to categorize / catalogue some data from an HTML file. 
Here's the file's data structure:

```
<fieldset>
<h3 class="specTitle">Section Title</h3>
<legend style="display:none;">|</legend>
<dl><dt>ItemLabel</dt><dd>Label</dd></dl>
</fieldset>
```

I'd like a spreadsheet out of it where one or more pages could be aligned like so:

```
Section Title
Item Label     Label
Item Label     Label
```

If I had to guess, that would look something like this as CSV:

```
,,
,Section Title,
,Item Label,Label
```

Thanks Everyone!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting.

Comment: What language are you doing this in?

Comment: Hi Nelles, either bash or a combination of things if anyone knows a good linux tool to convert HTML to CSV similar to the html2text package. Thx